# Java MongoDB driver version 3.8 -- how to set timeout?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java-3.8

I am maintaining a JSP/Servlet application that uses the MongoDB 3.8 Java driver. At this point, I cannot change versions to a newer one.

I have occasionally experienced some timeouts when connecting from the application to the database. Based on what I read in https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/ I wrote the following code:

```
    CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
    MongoCredential credential
      = MongoCredential.createCredential(theuser, database, thepassword.toCharArray());
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
      .credential(credential)
      .codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)
      .applyToClusterSettings(builder
        -> builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(addr, 27017))))
      .build();
    MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

This works, but with the eventual timeout (usually when reloading a JSP page).

I figured out I could create a `SocketSettings` instance with:

```
SocketSettings socketOptions = SocketSettings.builder().connectTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

But I cannot figure out how to apply these settings to the creation of the instance of `MongoClient`. Any hints?

thanks

Comment: There may be an option within `MongoClientSettings.Builder` to apply the settings.

Comment: @prasad_ yes, that's what I am looking for. Could not figure it out from the documentation.